# How to find whether an element is Visible or not using protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

On a page need to check whether an element is visible or not.

The element HTML code is as below:

```
    <li ng-class="{active: (subview == 'add')}" ng-show="iSU || dp.ua" class="ng-hide">
      <a href="#/setup/users/all/add/" lid="users-submenu-create-user-tab" class="ng-binding">
        Create user
      </a>
   </li>
```

I need to check the element 'Create user' is visible or not. If an element is hidden then the parent class will be "ng-hide".

I tried many ways to check the element but couldn't succeed.

//there is a custom method for the 'lid', we use this to identify the element.

expect(util.isCreateUserTabDisplayed()).toBe(false);

**Solution 1:**
Definition of "isCreateUserTabDisplayed()"

```
this.isCreateUserTabDisplayed = function()
    {
       var createUserTab = elmenet(by.lid("users-submenu-create-user-tab"));
        return createUserTab.isPresent()
    }
```

isPresent() returned "true" as the element exists in the DOM.

**Solution 2:**

Thought of Verify through isDisplayed() function

```
this.isCreateUserTabDisplayed = function()
        {
           var createUserTab = elmenet(by.lid("users-submenu-create-user-tab")).getWebElement();
           var createUserParentEle = createUserTab.getDriver();
            createUserParentEle.isDisplayed().then(function(result){
               return result;
            });
        }
```

Got the error "createUserParentEle.isDisplayed" is not a function

**Solution 3:**
Thought of verifying by getting the parent element class variable and verify it should be 'ng-hide'

```
this.isCreateUserTabDisplayed = function()
    {
               var createUserTab = elmenet(by.lid("users-submenu-create-user-tab")).getWebElement();
               var createUserParentEle = createUserTab.getDriver();
              return createUserParentEle.getAttribute('class').then(function(attrValue){
                       if( attrValue  == 'ng-hide')
                          return false
                       else
                          return true;
                  });
     }
```

Got the error "createUserParentEle.getAttribute" is not a function

Please anyone help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice a lot of questions on stackoverflow about protractor come out because users tend to overcomplicate things, whereas the solution maybe fairly simple

I highly recommend to always start with protractor documentation first, it has everything you need with examples

In your case [isDisplayed()](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isDisplayed) is what you're looking for

```
this.isCreateUserTabDisplayed = function() {
  var createUserTab = elmenet(by.lid("users-submenu-create-user-tab"));
  return createUserTab.isDisplayed()
}

// and use like this
expect(await this.isCreateUserTabDisplayed()).toBe(true);

// or if you don't know how to use await/async, which I recommend to learn too
this.isCreateUserTabDisplayed().then(function(result){
   expect(result).toBe(true);
})
```